# WP 7 Listbox with different cell height

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to build a ListBox with 3 different cell types.
I made the type selection using a TemplateSelector.
This selects the CellType correctly, but not the cell Height.

I want the Cell header to be 50px and the other cell types 110px.
But the Style defined in the  tag overrides the cell height.

I've tried writing the Style in the Grid element but it has no effect.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<delay:DeferredLoadListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:CellTemplateSelector
            Content="{Binding}">
                <local:CellTemplateSelector.CellHeader>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid
                            Name="MainGrid"
                            Width="480"
                            Height="50">
                            <Image />
                            <TextBlock />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:CellTemplateSelector.CellHeader>

                <local:CellTemplateSelector.GrayCell>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid
                            Name="MainGrid"
                            Width="480"
                            Height="110">
                            <Image />
                            <TextBlock />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:CellTemplateSelector.GrayCell>

                <local:CellTemplateSelector.WhiteCell>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid
                            Name="MainGrid"
                            Width="480"
                            Height="110">
                            <Image />
                            <TextBlock />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:CellTemplateSelector.WhiteCell>

        </local:CellTemplateSelector>
    </DataTemplate>
</delay:DeferredLoadListBox.ItemTemplate>

<delay:DeferredLoadListBox.Resources>
    <Style
        TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter
            Property="Height"
            Value="110" />
    </Style>
</delay:DeferredLoadListBox.Resources>

<delay:DeferredLoadListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</delay:DeferredLoadListBox.ItemsPanel>
</delay:DeferredLoadListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this out using your code, and found the simplest solution to your problem was to remove the Height property setter from the Style block completely. If you let the DataTemplates set their own height, using the techniqe you are already employing, it should behave exactly as you intend.

/chris

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer Chris.
I used a different approach:

```
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

   <toolkit:LongListSelector
                    x:Name="citiesListGropus"
                    Background="White"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContentCellTemplate}"
                    GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ActualityGroupHeaderTemplate}"
                    Margin="0,66,0,0" Grid.Row="1" MouseEnter="citiesListGropus_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="citiesListGropus_MouseLeave">
```

......................

From here:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034

ContentCellTemplate  and ActualityGroupHeaderTemplate are templates for each cell type.